# Subdivision Surface Error

Tags: subdivision-surface

I am trying to make a base mesh using the skin modifier in Blender 2.8, but every time I get to the Subdivision Surface Modifier,the top is left flat.
How do I fix that?
[image]

Comment: What does the mesh look like without the modifiers? And what is the full stack of modifiers?

Comment: I presume it could be that due to a double vertex in the base mesh the top square also has double vertices after the skin modifier, so the edge might be actually rounded just between two points at the same location ;) You could try if this is correct, by selecting the base mesh in edit mode and doing "merge by distance"